# going back to the parent activity on pressing app icon button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

hi there im a  android beginner, i just finish the android actionbar tutorial section [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav). my problem is on Add Up Button for Low-level Activities subject. i done it  but the only problem i have is i don't know why it doesn't come back to main activity when i press Up button. it just stay in child activity when i run app:
this is my MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.action;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaymessageactivity);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            case R.id.home:
            {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public void openSearch()
    {
        TextView textv=new TextView(this);
        textv.setText("Search");
        textv.setTextSize(50);
        setContentView(textv);
    }
    public void openSettings()
    {
        TextView textv=new TextView(this);
        textv.setText("Search");
        textv.setTextSize(50);
        setContentView(textv);
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.action"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.action.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
        android:name="com.example.Action.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.Action.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.Action.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and in addition i create a xml file named displaymessageactivity.xml in layout folder without this file i got an error in the main activity setcontentview command.

i say again my problem is : why i can not going back to mainActivity when i press Up button that is  next to app icon.
thanks

Comment: You are staying inside the MainActivity the whole time. You are just changing the content of your screen. This means you have to add a custom back behavior to change your content to what you want and not use the Navigation Utils. Or just start a new Activity when you press Search or Settings.

Comment: i added a message on textview in DisplayMessageActivity.xml file and when i start the app i see the textview  that i have added to DisplayMessageActivity.xml

Comment: That is because your MainActivity is based on your DisplayMessageActivity.xml: setContentView(R.layout.displaymessageactivity);

Comment: but in tutorial say we don't need to handle up button

Comment: Correct, back behavior is handled by default. You should create a new Activity for each time you call setContentView(..) and then your back behavior will work fine.

Comment: where should i have to create activity should i have to create a new activity in  case R.id.home: section

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51196/discussion-between-hussein-and-droidbender)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in the switch case.**

```
case android.R.id.home:
finish();
return true;
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem but just kill the application.

Comment: DroidBender say right it just kill the application and not show the mainActivity content

Comment: @Hussein you need to use different activity for different content, then only it will work

Comment: That would "kill" the application if it's put in the main activity. The question is about returning to the main activity, so this would work if put in onOptionsItemSelected on the called activity. Easy to get confused in this case because Mark put the code of MainActivity and not that of the called one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use lower case letters for package names in your manifest.e.g. com.example.action
2. setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) in DisplayMessageActivity.java class to return you to your MainActivity class which is the parent activity.
3. onOptionsItemSelected for your DisplayMessageActivity class remove case R.id.home and your switch default and return appropriately for the method. For example..`

.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true; 
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}`
```